# offical way of backing up live git

Tags: backup, git

I can't find an official guide on how to backup a "live" git repository.

The very first result in google when you search something like that is:

https://joeyh.name/blog/entry/difficulties_in_backing_up_live_git_repositories/

Even KDE flolks were using an approach that led to disaster:

http://jefferai.org/2013/03/29/distillation/

I can read answers to stackoverflow, serverfault, blogs... but it looks to me there's a lot of confusion. And that devil is in the details: my understanding of the "KDE incident" is that they were supposed to run `git fsck` after `git clone`, since `git clone` doesn't check for errors (but, again, nothing about that in the git manual...)

So: what is the official way of backing up a live git repository? Is something available in the manual about backing up?

Answer (score 2):

[git bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) is helpful here. I've been using this for a while now:

```
base_dir=/home/git
for gitrepo in `ls -d *.git`
do
 echo '**********[' ${gitrepo} ']***********'
 repo_name=${gitrepo%.git}
 echo cd ${base_dir}/${gitrepo}
 cd ${base_dir}/${gitrepo}
 backup_cmd="git bundle create /opt/git-backups/${repo_name}.bundle master"
 verify_command="git bundle verify /opt/git-backups/${repo_name}.bundle master"
 backup_cmd_all="git bundle create /opt/git-backups/${repo_name}-all.bundle --all"
 verify_command_all="git bundle verify /opt/git-backups/${repo_name}-all.bundle "
 echo -------- master only -------------------
 ${backup_cmd}
 echo -------- all -------------------
 ${backup_cmd_all}
 echo
 echo
done
```

The key is to test it all by restoring it on a test server every few weeks. Wrap some logging around that and get reports each time you use it, make it log the checksums of the files it generates, how long each one took etc. When the world is in flames around you and you need to restore doing the prep now will save you a lot of heartache.

Remember: It hasn't been backed up until it has been restored.

I'm not sure if there is any "official" way of backing up a git repo, there are lots of ways of backup up a git repo, tar, zip, filesystem dump etc., it's going to depend heavily on things like the size of the backup window.